# Namespaces in C Headers

Tags: c++, c, namespaces, extern

We have a code base where there are .cpp and .h, it is set up to be build with gcc

my understanding is that gcc will choose the appropriate compiler for the appropriate files so I believe (and testing has made me almost 100% sure) that our .h files are compiled as c and our .cpp files are compiled as C++.

I once tried to change to g++ and got a whole spate of errors, the same is true when I try and use .hpp.

So to get around the issue, most of the time I just use extern C++ when I need to (e.g. when including map)

However I can't seem to get it right for namespaces. I assume the compiler is complaining about my namespace because it is being compiled as .h? is this correct. My current code looks like (after trying it without the extern):

in foo.h

```
 extern "C++" {
 namespace Caching_Logic
 {
      class foo
      {
         ....
      }
 }
 }
```

in bar.h

```
 extern "C++" {
       using namespace Caching_Logic; //completely defeats the point of namespaces
 }
 class bar
 {
   ....

          foo m_foo;

   ...
 }
```

Both files are included by .cpp files

and the error when compiling is:

filethatusesbar.cpp: error: ‘class bar’ has no member named ‘m_foo’

bar.h : error: ‘Caching_Logic’ is not a namespace-name

bar.h : error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token

I am considering just giving up on the namespace entirely but I really like to scope my code for this!

-----UPDATE------

After reading http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_54.html

I have a slightly better understanding of what gcc does. originally I read somewhere that gcc compiles in C++ when necessary and in C when it comes across a .c

This is true but it would seem that there is then a problem with the linker. As this is compiled as a library it makes sense that i have not seen an issue before. I am guessing that this is related to my scope issue, external linkage?

Comment: You don't need (and in most cases, shouldn't even have) `extern "C++"`.  That's the default.  And even if your headers were compiled as C (which they're not), AFAIK a standard C compiler wouldn't even know what to do with `extern "C++"`, let alone any mention of classes and namespaces.  That's all C++ syntax.

Comment: C knows nothing about namespaces. Why do you think it would compile?

Comment: I have found extern "C++" to work in the past, as mentioned in my post

if i #include map

in the header file, it does not like it, however if I wrap it in

Comment: extern C++ it works

I think ultimately the problem here is, although gcc will compile a cpp source file as c++ and can clearly pick up on the extern C++ it ultimately links as if i was all c

 http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_54.html

so i think really I do have to act as if I am in C

Comment: If your header were processed as C you would get errors like; "error: expected identifier or '(' before string constant." You can try compiling your header as c source code by running a command like `gcc -c -x c foo.h`. The fact that you're not getting an error on source like `extern "C++" {`, which is not valid C, proves that your header is not being processed as C. You may need to learn more about the compilation model of C and C++, because headers simply aren't processed the way you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Your .h files are not compiled as C. They're included in your *.cpp files, and the preprocessed combination is compiled by your C++ compiler.

Verify that you have #included foo.h somewhere before the problem line in bar.h. Failing to do so could cause the compiler error. Prefer to #include it in bar.h, which best knows its own physical dependencies.

The using directive in bar.h is considered harmful, as noted by the comment. Consider using this instead:

```
class bar {
    ....
    Caching_Logic::foo m_foo;
```

Comment: and it is definitely included

Comment: Yes, the scope operator didn't work either, thats why i tried the using namespace just to see if it worked. My errors were from that compile and were a little cleaner so thats the code i posted

Comment: Other things to try: copy/paste the namespace name, to ensure it's identical; simplify by removing the unnecessary extern "C++" bracketing; use g++ -E to get the pre-processed output, and verify that foo.h's contents appear before bar.h's, and appear as expected after pre-processing.

Comment: can I ask why the extern C++ makes a difference if they are not compiled in c?

Comment: One general tactic to solving compiler errors is to simplify the problem so that it's easier to understand, and to eliminate potential contributors to the problem. Here, the extern C++ is likely innocent. But you can easily guarantee that it's not a factor by eliminating it.

Comment: Moving the .cpp file up to the top of the source list seems to have solved the problem, I would have thought this wouldnt matter, due to the namespace & class being declared in the .h file?

Comment: ok it didnt solve the problem, i am getting the error:

‘Caching’ does not name a type

Like you say Andy, I am going to have to simplify this, I think i will have to go away and write a test program, see if i can reproduce the issue in a smaller code base and for now just not use namespace